# Bootstrap 12 colums of size 1 on extra small screen dont fiit

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am trying to do what the title says, but in a small screen (like my phone) the 12 columns don't fit on the row.
I have also tried this on Foundation but the results are the same.

Example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">3</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">5</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">7</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">9</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">10</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">11</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">12</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Or here on the file I am working on:
Edit: no loger true since I fixed it.

Is this the expected behavior? Can this be fixed, and if so what would be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the space between divs. Add this CSS to your "row" div:

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-xs-']{padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0}
```

In html:

```
<div class="row no-gutter">
...
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you, I didn't see that.